# EC2 host name unique across multiple AWS accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

in a scenario where you have let's say an AWS infrastructure with more than 10 OU and 100 accounts... Each account has a VPC where a specific app is running on a EC2 instance. Is it possible to make sure the EC2 instances have a unique hostname across all accounts?

I'm using terraform to provision the instances but I'm not sure how I can make it check if the hostname I'm trying to use while creating the instance is existing already or not...

I'm open to suggestions for this situation.

Comment: I can think of two different approaches. First you could just always include the account ID in the hostname, which will be unique for each account. Alternatively, for more sophisticated requirements, you will need to have a centrally-managed store of details like this which you can check (or retrieve a new name from).

Comment: @lxop I'm thinking of using a dynamoDB table and check using terraform (conditional logic) if the table contains the hostname or not... do you think this might be a good approach?

Comment: Just use the `instance-id` -- it is globally unique across AWS.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Perfect! Thought it was only unique within 1 account! I can mark the answer as valid if you just put it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are seeking a unique identifier for Amazon EC2 instances, you can use the `Instance ID`.

From [Resource IDs - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/resource-ids.html):

> When resources are created, we assign each resource a unique resource ID. A resource ID takes the form of a resource identifier (such as snap for a snapshot) followed by a hyphen and a unique combination of letters and numbers.
>
> Each resource identifier, such as an AMI ID, instance ID, EBS volume ID, or EBS snapshot ID, is tied to its Region and can be used only in the Region where you created the resource.

Don't worry -- each region is generating the ID from its own value range. Thus, the ID is also globally unique.

**Fun fact:** In 2016 the ID format was changed from 8 characters (`i-1a2b3c4d`) to 17 characters (`i-1234567890abcdef0`) because the usage of AWS grew so much!

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein, just a question that crossed my mind... would the hostname be lost if the instance restarts? is there a way to keep the hostname attached to the instance even after it's restart?

Comment: Hostnames would not be affected by a restart. (But let us know if you find otherwise!)